# Pandas Filter rows by comparing columns A1 with A2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

| CHR | SNP | BP | A1 | A2 | OR | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | rs62513865 | 101592213 | T | C | 1.00652 | 0.8086 |
| 8 | rs79643588 | 106973048 | A | T | 1.01786 | 0.4606 |

I have this table example, and I want to filter rows by comparing column A1 with A2.
If this four conditions happen, delete the line

| A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | T |
| T | A |
| C | G |
| G | C |

(e.g. line 2 in the first table).
How can i do that using python **Pandas** ?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it
Combine the two columns for each of the two DF. Make it a list in case of the second DF and search the first combination in the second one

```
df[~(df['A1']+df['A2']).str.strip()
   .isin(df2['A1']+df2['A2'].tolist())]
```

```
    CHR     SNP     BP  A1  A2  OR  P
0   8   rs62513865  101592213   T   C   1.00652     0.8086
```

Answer (score 0):

##### keeping

Assuming `df1` and `df2`, you can simply `merge` to keep the common values:

```
out = df1.merge(df2)
```

output:

```
   CHR         SNP         BP A1 A2       OR       P
0    8  rs79643588  106973048  A  T  1.01786  0.4606
```

##### dropping

For removing the rows, perform a negative merge:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
          .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
       )
```

Or `merge` and get the remaining indices to `drop` (requires unique indices):

```
out = df1.drop(df1.reset_index().merge(df2)['index'])
```

output:

```
   CHR         SNP           BP A1 A2       OR       P
0  8.0  rs62513865  101592213.0  T  C  1.00652  0.8086
```

##### alternative approach

As it seems you have nucleotides and want to drop the cases that do not match a A/T or G/C pair, you could translate A to T and C to G in A1 and check that the value is not identical to that of A2:

```
m = df1['A1'].map({'A': 'T', 'C': 'G'}).fillna(df1['A1']).ne(df1['A2'])

out = df1[m]
```